# Pass multiple data in ajax

Tags: php, ajax

```
         <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#btn").click(function(){
                var from=$('input#searchfrom').val();
                var to=$('input#searchto').val();
                datastring="from="+from+"&to="+to;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "measure.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                   beforeSend: function(){ $("#btn").val('Connecting...').delay(6000);},
                    success:function(response){
                    $('#result').html(response);}
              });

            });
          });
        </script>
```

Follow are the element which hold the value

```
        From-<input id="searchfrom" type="text" size="50" placeholder="Enter a location" autocomplete="on">
                     To-<input id="searchto" onblur="" type="text" size="50" placeholder="Enter a location" autocompete="on" >
                     <div id="result"></div>
                     <button type="button" id="btn" >Click</button>
```

Ajax function can not pass the data in mesaure page but its properly work when one argument pass please help me to solve out this problem  thanks.

Comment: did you `console.log` the value of `from` and `to` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like below:
Html content:

```
<form id="searchForm">
 <input id="searchfrom" name="searchfrom" type="text" size="50" placeholder="Enter a location" autocomplete="on">
                     To-<input id="searchto" name="searchto" onblur="" type="text" size="50" placeholder="Enter a location" autocompete="on" >
                     <div id="result"></div>
                     <button type="button" id="btn" >Click</button>
</form>
```

JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btn").click(function(){
            datastring=$('#searchForm').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "measure.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
               beforeSend: function(){ $("#btn").val('Connecting...').delay(6000);},
                success:function(response){
                $('#result').html(response);}
          });

        });
      });
    </script>
```